# Appsheet how do I check if the value can be divided by 30?

Tags: google-appsheet

I am trying to check the time of duration must be 30 minute per unit.
My data are like this  "MINUTE([time])"  which return a number.
Any idea how I can achieve this?

I tried to validate like this "([_THISROW] % 30) = 0" but error return: "Expression '([_THISROW] % 30) = 0' was unable to be parsed: Expression '([_THISROW] % 30) = 0' does not match the expected format of an AppSheet expression."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using this expression.

```
OR(
  MINUTE([time]) / 60 = 0.50, 
  MINUTE([time]) / 60 = 0.00
)
```

`MINUTE` get the duration time of the minute.
For example 2hr 30 minute will return 30. Than caculate and validate.